# How does Sven Great Cleave interact with enemy armor?

Tags: dota-2

I was looking at Sven's Greate Cleave on [Dota 2 Wiki](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Sven) and its notes it is written:

> Cleave damage is reduced by armor type but not by armor value.
>
> Cleave damage goes through magic immunity.

Now I have two questions:

- The fact that it goes through magic immunity it means that the damage is physical?
- What does it mean that it is reduced by armor type but not by armor value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does it mean that it is reduced by armor type but not by armor value?

When the wiki mentions armor type, its taking about the class of the [armor](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Armor) on the target.  I.e. hero armor, creep armor, building armor.  So if great cleave hits a hero, it will still do only 75% of the regular damage due to the hero armor bonus, but the value of the hero armor will not affect damage done.

> The fact that it goes through magic immunity it means that the damage is physical?

Not quite, there are some magical damage that can go through magic immunity ([March of the Machines](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Tinker#March_of_the_Machines), for example.)

In this case, it probably does mean that its considered physical damage.